# how to link storyboard outlets and actions to custom category methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am writing a simple app with custom storyboards for iPhone and iPad.  I have a generic viewcontroller class from which my custom iPhone and iPad viewcontrollers inherit.  Outlets and IBActions in my storyboards are mostly wired up to the generic viewController class and everything works well.

Now for stylistic reasons I decided to make my iPhone's viewcontroller be a UITableViewController and it can no longer inherit from my generic viewcontroller.  I've been googling and searching this site and see advice which says I should write a category and use this in my custom classes.

I have never done this, but I looked at the documentation and understand the concept, but once I move my code into a category, how would I be able to link my storyboard's outlets and actions (ctrl-drag from storyboard) to the methods which are now moved out of my custom viewcontroller classes?  Usually I would for example ctrl-drag from a switch in the storyboard to an existing IBAction method in my generic viewController, but these methods will now be inherited and not showing my my custom classes to drag to.

I am just a hobbyist and newb, so I apologize if this question is too basic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIViewController` with `UITableView` instead of `UITableViewController`.

1.In storyboard, get a new `UIViewController` and linking with your custom `viewcontroller` class.After that,put an `UITableView` into that `UIViewController` and linking with that class using (ctrl-drag from storyboard) called `mTableView`

2.In that class you should implement `<UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>`.
Use `mTableView` instead of `self.tableView` just like in `UITableViewController`.

Comment: I tried this, but I am using static table view cells and the compiler tells me I must use a UITableViewController for this (otherwise must use dynamic).  Any other ideas?

Comment: you also can use static table view with this method

Comment: The compiler tells me "Illegal Configuration.  Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances" :(

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/NavBar.zip This is a project showing how to custom navigation bar.You will find a static table view in `ExtendedNavBarViewController` to help you.